# How to isolate a file path into separate columns?

Tags: sql

I would like to separate a file path into separate columns. The code below works in most cases but it is not working for the example case below. It seems to not work in cases that have words repeated. The example code goes up to three columns, but it would repeat, as some file paths are longer. Using SQL Sever 2008.

I have thousands of rows like:

```
Garden Center|Seeds|Flower Seeds|Organic Flower Seeds
```

Desired output:

```
Path1
Garden Center

Path2
Seeds

Path3
Flower Seeds

Path4
Organic Flower Seeds
```

Currently I am getting:

```
Path1
Garden Center

Path2
Seeds

Path3
Flower Organic Flower Seeds
```

--Code:

```
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
DROP TABLE #TEMP2
DROP TABLE #TEMP3

SELECT 
ID_Ref,
CollectionPath,
CollectionPath AS Path_a,
CollectionPath AS Path_1,
CollectionPath AS Path_b,
CollectionPath AS Path_2,
CollectionPath AS Path_c,
CollectionPath AS Path_3

INTO #TEMP1
FROM DATA



UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_a = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',CollectionPath) > 0 THEN

 REPLACE(CollectionPath,LEFT(CollectionPath+'|', CHARINDEX('|',CollectionPath+'|')),'')


    ELSE
    NULL
END 
)


UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_1 = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',Path_a) > 0 THEN

 SUBSTRING(Path_a,1,CHARINDEX('|',Path_a)-1)


    ELSE
    NULL
END 
)


UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_b = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',Path_a) > 0 THEN

  REPLACE(Path_a,LEFT(Path_a+'|', CHARINDEX('|',Path_a+'|')),'')


    ELSE
    NULL
END 
)


UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_2 = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',Path_b) > 0 THEN

    SUBSTRING(Path_b,1,CHARINDEX('|',Path_b)-1)


    ELSE(
    CASE WHEN Path_b IS NOT NULL THEN Path_b
    ELSE NULL
    END
    )

END 
)


UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_c = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',Path_b) > 0 THEN

  REPLACE(Path_b,LEFT(Path_b+'|', CHARINDEX('|',Path_b+'|')),'')


    ELSE
    NULL
END 
)


UPDATE #TEMP1
SET Path_3 = (
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('|',Path_c) > 0 THEN

    SUBSTRING(Path_c,1,CHARINDEX('|',Path_c)-1)


    ELSE(
    CASE WHEN Path_c IS NOT NULL THEN Path_c
    ELSE NULL
    END
    )

END 
)


SELECT ID_Ref, CollectionPath, 
Path_a,
Path_1,
Path_b,
Path_2,
Path_c,
Path_3

INTO #TEMP2
FROM #TEMP1

SELECT SC.CollectionPath,
Path_a,
Path_1,
Path_b,
Path_2,
Path_c,
Path_3

INTO #TEMP3 

FROM DATA SC

LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMP2 ON SC.ID_Ref = #TEMP2.ID_Ref

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP3
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL *Flavor*)?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of an existing question (which one depends on RDBMS).  Most of the existing ones either use a recursive CTE (which I've done in DB2), or a split/pivot function if they have them (usually better).  _Why_ are you doing this?  Storing a complete path is completely valid, especially for certain optimization cases... now, if you're building your permanent tree-table, I'd understand.